# Change of basis question from an exercise about finite Banach spaces and their duals

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

The exercise in question is from Hunter's Applied Analysis, specifically exercise 5.2.

Here is given an n-dimensional space $X$, with bases $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ and $\{\tilde{e}_1,\ldots,\tilde{e}_n\}$. The bases are related by a matrix $(L_{ij})$ with inverse $(\tilde{L}_{ij})$, such that
$$
   \tilde{e}_i = \sum_{j=1}^n L_{ij}e_j;\qquad e_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \tilde{L}_{ij}\tilde{e}_j;\qquad \delta_{ik} = \sum_{j=1}^n L_{ij}\tilde{L}_{jk},
$$
where $\delta_{ik}$ is the Kronecker delta function.

Additionally we are given the dual bases $\{\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n\}$ and $\{\tilde{\omega}_1,\ldots,\tilde{\omega}_n\}$ of $X^*$.

To prove:

a) If $x=\sum x_ie_i = \sum\tilde{x}_i\tilde{e}_i\in X$, then $$\tilde{x}_i = \tilde{L}_{ij}x_j.$$

b) If $\phi=\sum\phi_i\omega_i = \sum\tilde{\phi}_i\tilde{\omega}_i\in X^*$, then $$\tilde{\phi}_i=L_{ji}\phi_j.$$

I am still stuck at a) (and would not appreciate answers for b) just yet, maybe perhaps small hints), and what I managed to derive is that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j=1}^n\tilde{L}_{ij}\tilde{e}_j = \sum_{j=1}^n\tilde{e}_j\sum_{i=1}^n\tilde{L}_{ij}x_i=\sum_{j=1}^n\tilde{e}_j\tilde{x}_j,
$$
which implies that $\tilde{x}_i = \sum_{j=1}^n\tilde{L}_{ji}x_j$. This should make sense, and every textbook and online source I searched lead me to a similar answer, which contradicts a). Notice that even the indices are switched, and nothing is stated about $j$ in the question. Am I missing something here, or there is simply an error in the exercise?

Comment: There is what is called the 'summation convention' (not used by Mathematicians) according to which a summation is automatically applied to repeated indices. Since this book is on Applied Mathematics it may be using this convention.

Comment: While the book does have "applied" in its title, it is still a purely (functional) analysis book, with applications *in* mathematics. If they indeed used such a convention, why use it all of a sudden right there? I believe that there are two possibilities for error: 1) perhaps they mean that $\tilde{x}_i = \tilde{L}_{ii}x_i$; or 2) they indeed forgot the summation symbol and wrote $\tilde{L}_{ij}$ instead of $\tilde{L}_{ji}$. But then the same mistake is also repeated in b) ??? I checked the latest errata, and this exercise is not on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything here, and I think Kavi is right...or the book made an error.

In particular, you can prove that the assumptions imply that $\overline{x}_j=L_{ij}x_j$ for all $j$ does not necessarily happen.

Your derivation shows that
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \overline{x}_j\overline{e}_j=\sum_{j=1}^n \overline{e}_j\left[ \sum^n_{i=1} \overline{L}_{ij} x_i \right],$$
hence $\overline{x}_j=\sum^n_{i=1} \overline{L}_{ij} x_i$. So $\overline{x}_j=\overline{L}_{ij}x_j$, for all $j$ implies that $\overline{x}_j=0$, hence $x=0$.

But we have the simple counterexample of $X=\mathbb{R}$, $e_1=\overline{e}_1=1$, $L_{ij}=[1]$, and $x=1$, showing that this doesn't necessarily happen.

I think it's safe to assume what Kavi did and interpret the book as using the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

I'm going to respect your wishes and not give an answer (or a hint) for part (b).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Assuming Einstein's notation, there still is an error in that what we derived is $\bar{x}_i = \bar{L}_{ji}x_j$, but a) requires that $\bar{x}_i = \bar{L}_{ij}x_j$. This leads me to believe that $\bar{e}_i = \sum_{j=1}^n L_{ij}e_j$ should be $\bar{e}_i = \sum_{j=1}^n L_{ji}e_j$ instead. I wonder if that is also the case for $e_i$, because then the answer for b) would also be incorrect. On a side note, it's really annoying to be stuck on such a simple problem because of errors.